# CCMenu misplaced under iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, ccmenu

Under iOS 6 all my CCMenus appeared centered on the screen by default, if I did not assign an explicit position. **Under iOS 7 the menus are positioned off screen**.

Do I have to assign an explicit position under iOS 7?

### **iOS 6:**

[image]

### **iOS 7:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are **two underlying problems**.

1. If you have hidden your status bar under iOS 6, this will not work for iOS 7 without adding an additional value to your *Info.plist* ([View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/279/hiding-status-bar-ccmenu-fix-ios7))
2. Due to a bug in Cocos2D your screen size will be calculated wrong, if your status bar is visible.

You have to different options to **solve this problem**:

1. Set a CCMenu position explicitly instead of using the implicit
   positioning (e.g: `menu.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);`)
2. Set [View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/279/hiding-status-bar-ccmenu-fix-ios7) in your *Info.plist* if you don't want to show the status bar anyway